# How can i Check if logged in user is admin or members of the administrators group in javascript

Tags: extjs, aem, jcr

I want to show button on page if logged in user is admin or members of the administrators group in javascript.

I am able to get

```
CQ.User.getCurrentUser()
```

but not able to check if user is admin. Please suggest.

Comment: Don't do this on clientside - ever. If I see your page and go through it's source, I can change the JS a bit, run it and then I'll have the button - is this what you want? You should make this check on the backend side.

Comment: TS want to show button based on user role, not give any permissions on cliend side. Its absolutly legit, no reason to render this button on server side. On server side we have to check permissions on every request.

Answer (score 1):

You could create some node in the CRX repository and apply a proper permissions (e.g. Administrators group can read the node, others don't have any permissions to the node).

When you apply permissions, then you could execute following code:

```
if (CQ.User.getCurrentUser().hasPermissionOn("read", "path_to_your_node") === true) {
    // add a button
}
```

This solution is correct because generally in AEM world we shouldn't relay on user login or name of groups, instead of these we should relay on permissions which current user has.